# How display value on axe ylabel2

Tags: gnuplot

This is my code:

```
set title "courbe"
set xlabel "first" 
set ylabel "second"
set y2label "third"
plot "File.txt" using 1:2 with linespoints tit 'first', "File.txt" using 1:3 with linespoints tit 'second', "File.txt" using 1:4 with points tit 'third'
```

Please, the third axe does not display numbers on the axe ..have you an idea please ?
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that's the actual script you used to generate that plot because the titles for the second plot command don't match.  Barring that, you're not actually plotting anything on the y2 axes.  To put something on the y2 axis, you need to specify that explicitly (e.g. `axes x1y2`).  Something like:

```
set title "courbe"
set xlabel "first" 
set ylabel "second"
set y2label "third"
plot "File.txt" using 1:2 with linespoints title 'first',\
     "File.txt" using 1:3 with linespoints title 'second', \
     "File.txt" axes x1y2 using 1:4 with points title 'third'
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i have this error:    Bad data on line 1
Have you an idea please ?

Comment: @user1735757 -- If the datafile is reasonably short, you could post that along with the actual script that you're working on so that we have something to play around with.  Without seeing the datafile and the actual script you're using, I'd only be guessing.